# Error Executing Stored Procedure that References Linked Server with PyMSSQL

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure from a python script, via pymssql, that communicates with a linked server.  The SP works when run manually, but when run from the python script errors out with:

```
(7391, 'The operation could not be performed because OLE DB 
provider"SQLNCLI11" for linked server "DBLOG" was unable to begin a 
distributed transaction.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:
\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n')
```

I haven't been able to find anything that references this as a limitation within pymssql itself.  I'm not quite sure where to start.  I do quite a bit of work with pymssql and have never had any connection issues, and I have verified that the login I am using has sufficient permissions (I even tried using SA).

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to recreate the issue with an SP that tried to do an UPDATE on the linked server, e.g.,

```sql
UPDATE LINKEDSERVERNAME...TableName SET ...
```

although my error message was slightly different

> (8501, "MSDTC on server 'PANORAMA\SQLEXPRESS' is unavailable.DB-Lib error message 20018, ...

I was able to avoid the issue by adding an `autocommit=True` argument to the end of my `pymssql.connect` call.

If for some reason using `autocommit=True` is no good for you then have a look at

[MSDTC on server 'server is unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29414250/2144390)

for information on configuring MSDTC.

Comment: This fixed that issue perfectly!  Now I'm just working through issues of my stored proc exiting seemingly randomly.  I took out all print statements and set nocount off, and that seemed like it fixed it. But now it's happening again occasionally.