# How to use Two SqlConnection in single TransactionScope in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have installed sql server 2008 R2 in two systems, from this one system act as a server and another is client.

I need to copy product from server system database to client system database

In my web.config

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="DBConnection" connectionString="Data Source=SERVER-PC\SQLEXPRESS2008;Initial Catalog=POS;Integrated Security=False;User Id=sa;Password=sql2008;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="DBConnection1" connectionString="Data Source=CLIENT-PC\SQLEXPRESS2008;Initial Catalog=POS;Integrated Security=False;User Id=sa;Password=sql2008;Connection Timeout=1;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Here My Coding

```
            using (TransactionScope trnsScope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            try
            {
                List<Master_ProductBLL> lstProduct = new List<Master_ProductBLL>();
                //My First SQL Connection For Server
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    //Here I can get All Products from Server Database
                    lstProduct = Master_ProductBLL.GetMaster_ProductBLLs(DBAction.Status.Active, "");
                    connection.Dispose();
                }

                //My Second SQL Connection For Client
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection1"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    //Here I have save my Server Product into Client SQL Server
                    foreach (Master_ProductBLL item in lstProduct)
                    {
                        item.Save(true);
                    }
                    connection.Dispose();
                }
                trnsScope.Complete();
                trnsScope.Dispose();
            }
            catch (TransactionException ex)
            {
                trnsScope.Dispose();
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

It shows an Error like
**MSDTC on server 'CLIENT-PC\SQLEXPRESS2008' is unavailable**

**Unable to get the address of the distributed transaction coordinator for the server, from the server.  Is DTC enabled on the server?**

I have google it and find the following details

1. go to Services. (START > SETTINGS > CONTROL PANEL > ADMINISTRATIVE TOOLS > SERVICES)
2. Find the service called 'Distributed Transaction Coordinator' and RIGHT CLICK (on it and select) > Start.
3. make this service to run Automatically for solving this issue permanently

I have done the above steps both server and client.

But Still have an error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29414250/msdtc-on-server-server-is-unavailable

Comment: are you stil getting the SAME error ?

Answer (score 1):

I think for two (or more) SQL servers to be transactionnaly 'synced', you have to configure network DTC as MSDTC service is in charge of a lot of stuff about transactions... (your client should use the server's one).

To do this :

- type dcomcnfg in run...
- open Component services | Computers
- Right click "Local Computer" and go to MSDTC tab
- uncheck Use a local coordinator and type in your server name (or IP)
- make sure you followed the steps mentionned in
  [MSDTC on server 'server is unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29414250/msdtc-on-server-server-is-unavailable)
  on both the client and the server.

Not really sure it'll work, but pretty sure it won't if you don't do that.

Answer (score -1):

Which database you want to use create object of that database.it is simple

```
SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString();

SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection1"].ConnectionString
```