# The DTC transaction failed to start. This could occur because the MSDTC Service is not running

Tags: ssis, msdtc

I am trying to run a Transaction Control Flow chain, where package is Required and all Sequence Containers have Supported Transaction Option.

I keep getting "The DTC transaction failed to start. This could occur because the MSDTC Service is not running."

I did all the online instruction I could find, enabled/disabled everything, (re) started all appropriate services, deleted and created registries, changed user(s) permissions, disabled and enabled firewalls, I let through firewall MSDTC and DTC apps... Still nothing works.

Has anyone solved this kind of a problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the SSIS Runtime fail to start the distributed transaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426780/why-does-the-ssis-runtime-fail-to-start-the-distributed-transaction)

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/122610/problem-creating-a-transaction-in-an-ssis-package